# Not Found mysql driver for fixture @Before in Unit test

Tags: java, junit, database-connection, fixtures

guys. I have a strange problem. I try to write unit-tests to web-app. I decided to check some methods (queries). It's a working app. But when I use fixture @Before

```
@Before
    public void setUp() throws ConnectionException {   
        Connection connection = null;    
        ConnectionPool.init();            
        connection = ConnectionPool.getInstance().takeConnection();
}
```

I have error when I initialised connection pool in Class.forName(driver).

With error
ClassNotFoundException: com.mysql.jdbc.Driver

I don't know. Maybe somebody knows cause.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add the MySQL connector JAR to your CLASSPATH when you run the test.

Comment: How I can do that (Netbeans 7.1 Ubuntu)?

Comment: Don't use an IDE if you don't know CLASSPATH: http://bits.netbeans.org/dev/javadoc/org-openide-modules/org/openide/modules/doc-files/classpath.html